# addSubview and addArrangedSubview not showing content

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I'm adding a `UILabel` to a `UIView` and then adding the `UIView` to a `UIStackView`, but the UILabel is not showing.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    configureStackView()
    
    label.text = "test"
    containerView.addSubview(label)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(containerView)
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    
    setStackViewConstraints()
}

func configureStackView() {
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 5
}

func setStackViewConstraints() {
     stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
     stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
     stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
     stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
     stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
 }
```

I tried setting some sort of size for the view, but doesn't work:

```swift
containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
```

or setting constraints to the label to the `containerView` for `widthAnchor`, `leadingAnchor`, or `trailingAnchor`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIView on its own does not have an `intrinsicContentSize`, which `UIStackView` uses to determine the size of the view when placed in the `stackView`.  Either set constraints for the four edges of the label to the edges of the container

```
label.topAnchor.constraint(container.topAnchor, constant: myTopConstant).isActive = true
label.leading....
label.bottom....
label.trailing....

label.setContentHuggingPriority(to: .defaultLow, axis: .vertical)
```

(above, relax the `contentHuggingPriority` if you are not placing any other views in the stackView; since it has a fixed height and `distribution = .fill`, your stackView will try to stretch the arrangedViews to fit the height.  If the label/container are the only candidates, you'll be breaking constraints with a `.required` contentHugging on the label)

or give the container a well-defined height (since the axis of your stackView is vertical)

```
containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ....).isActive = true
```

Also, in your container, set

```
translatesAutoresizing... = false
```